# Why isn't there an open source Stack Overflow clone written in ASP.NET?

Tags: discussion, open-source, clone

I've looked through the list in [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones), but it seems that Stacked is the only one available mentioned there, but it does not seem to be active.

I would be very eager to contribute to the open source version of an active ASP.NET clone of Stack Overflow.

Stack Exchange has a qualifying process and no-ownership policy. I would like one where I can make all kinds of necessary changes and commit it back to the main source. But I don't want to rally a community behind the Q&A before I can use it. I'm sure there are a lot of businesses out there who want a Q&A on their Website. Whether the community will thrive or not, sometimes it is hard to ascertain without putting it out there first. For example, my website has a niche which may take years to build a community. But that doesn't mean my Q&A is less relevant when there are not enough people rallying for it now. It is just that it may be ahead of its time for now.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote an open source clone in ASP.NET MVC called [Stack Underflow](https://github.com/ripper234/Stack-Underflow). My main reason to write it was to learn the technology, not to compete with Stack Overflow.

As to why it isn't developed now - there are two large open source clones I'm aware of - [Shapado](http://shapado.com/) and [OSQA](http://meta.osqa.net). Those seem to be doing very well and attracting a large user base. Even though I enjoy C# more than whatever programming languages those projects are bulit in, I think that the number one reason to choose an open source project to use (as a user, not developer) is its popularity, not how beautiful the code is. If those options have many active sites using them, I see no real point in developing any new C# based variant. If you want to work on good OSS clones - join/fork one of those projects.

Still - if for any reason you're insisting on a .NET based solution, you're always welcome to join or fork my project (I would love the ego boost :)

Comment: Sounds good. Will get in touch soon.

I reckon it is good to have a .Net alternative to StackOverflow clones since many people would not want to go through the community bidding process... I chose ASP .Net because I'm more comfortable innovating without the learning curve. Sometimes you just want to create those things without spending time finding out how to do it...

Comment: @Jason - I fully understand. However, I would advise you formulate your goals first. If your goal is to create a good Q&A site (not run by Stack Overflow LLC), then choosing either OSQA or Shapado is definitely the better option - those are stable projects, and you would "waste" much more time fixing bugs and adding features to Stack Underflow that you would waste by learning Ruby. If a good portion of your motivation comes from wanting to specifically learn Asp.Net MVC, and the goal of creating a good site is secondary, then Stack Underflow is for you.

Comment: Note - I wrote "join my project" - but I actually haven't touched the codebase in the last half a year. I will find the time to help you with whatever you need to get started ... and will always be available to answers questions, but I don't see myself heavily developing the project. But, who knows....

Answer (score 1):

There is one but not exactly a Stackoverflow type instead it's a Forum type with lots of Stackoverflow Features like badges and vote up and down and etc.
**http://www.mvcforum.com/**